# How to open save file dialog when i click on ok of a Message Box

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I would like to prompt the user for a save file dialog when he clicks on Ok of a message box displayed. How can i do this...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the answer this was what i am asking for

```
          MessageBox.Show("Save The Current File");
            if (Convert.ToBoolean( DialogResult.OK ))
            {
                SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
                saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";                  
                saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

                if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)                    
                    string s= saveFileDialog1.FileName;                    
            }
```

Comment: First I was going to say that this won't compile, but with a closing '}' it actually does. Then I was going to say that this code does not do what you expect it to do, but then again it actually does. Strange how two wrongs can be "right". But never the less, do not ever write such confusing code again.

Comment: I just write the sample so i missed the ending tag

Comment: Yes, but the problem is the line 'if (Convert.ToBoolean( DialogResult.OK ))'. If you add more buttons to the MessageBox (like OKCancel) this will always be true since you are not comparing with the result from the MessageBox, you just check that the CONSTANT DialogResult.OK is not zero. It looks like pure accident that it works in this particular case, but as soon as you add another button  to the MessageBox your code will fall apart.

Comment: For my purpose Ok is enough so i have did this

Answer (score 7):

In the event handler of the button, use the following code.

```
DialogResult messageResult = MessageBox.Show("Save this file?", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
if (messageResult == DialogResult.OK)
{
    using (var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog())
    {
        dialog.DefaultExt = "*.txt";
        dialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string filename = dialog.FileName;
            // Save here
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** If you want to get a **FileStream** directly you can use [`SaveFileDialog.OpenFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.SAVEFILEDIALOG.OPENFILE);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true). This requires less permissions if you run your application in partial trust.

Comment: Hi initially i will have a Messagebox with some text . When i click on ok i would like to open save file dialog

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/519bytz3.aspx MessageBox.Show() also returns a DialogResult you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

You could google this. If you have problem with click event. I guess you are using visual studio just double click the button on the design surface and write your code inside the handler that you go.

http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/csharp/save-file-dialog-example.htm

MessageBox.Show() returns DialogResult

```
  DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show("Is Dot Net Perls awesome?",
            "Important Question",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK);

  if (result1 == DialogResult.OK)
  { //Show SaveFileDialog }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        textBox1.Enabled=false;

            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Excell File |*.xlsx;*,xlsx";
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string extn = Path.GetExtension(ofd.FileName);
                if (extn.Equals(".xls") || extn.Equals(".xlsx"))
                {
                    filename = ofd.FileName;

                    if (filename != "")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            string excelfilename = Path.GetFileName(filename);                               
                        }
                        catch (Exception ew)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Errror:" + ew.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```